# How do I repeatedly merge a branch over time?

Tags: git

I am currently following a development process where I have 3 branches: **master**, **dev**, and **wip**.

The **dev** branch is basically a feature branch off of **master**. The **wip** branch is a daily update branch off **dev**. I use the **wip** branch to commit my work everyday and sync with a remote server so I can continue my work on another computer at a different location.

The **wip** branch may get 3 or 4 commits before I have enough work that I want to squash and make just 1 commit. Since the **wip** branch is pushed to a remote everyday, I cannot just squash the commits with rebase. Instead, I want to merge them and squash them into one commit on the **dev** branch. Then I want to continue develop on the **wip** branch. Then repeat these steps of merging and squashing indefinitely.

How do I go about doing this?

I tried using a merge --squash from **wip** to **dev**, but I think that makes my **dev** branch useless because the squashed commit does not share an ancestry with the **wip** branch, so the two branches have essentially diverged.

Is it better to do a merge --no-ff so I can continue developing on **wip**? Or should I do a fast forward merge and then interactive rebase the **dev** branch to squash the commits?

Here is a picture of what I want:

```
dev -A----------D----------H- ...
     |         /          /
wip -A--b--c--d--e--f--g--h- ...
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: _I cannot just squash the commits with rebase_.  Technically, you could, as long as _you can be sure_ no one else is using the **wip** branch.

Comment: Yea, I thought about that since the idea is really that the **wip** branch is only supposed to be mine. I was a little worried about accidents and thought there might be a better way that could avoid that potential issue. Maybe I shouldn't concern myself with it and just name the branch to reflect that it is personally mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** - Rereading your post, I realize I completely missed the `merge --squash` issue...  In fact the `rebase` approach I describe is essentially the same as doing a `merge --squash`, with the difference that it's more easily repeatable.  (Well, that and I didn't know about `--squash`, because I'm a n00b.)

Anyway, your concern about doing a `merge --squash` is that the branch "essentially diverged".  That's half true; there is no git ancestry link between the `D` and `d` commits if you do it that way (or by rebasing as I outline below).  But as long as you keep track of *how much of `wip` has been squashed onto `dev`*, it doesn't make either branch useless - their *content* has not diverged, only the topology.  (So that's why moving a tag to represent your last `--squash` or `rebase` can keep you out of trouble.)

But if you want to keep the topological relationship, then `--no-ff` merging is the way to go.  The problem seems to be that you like *some* things about having `D` know it's derived from `d`, and some things about having it not know; so you'll have to decide which you'd rather work around.

If it knows, then for example by default `log` is going to show the finer-grained history (but with the right options you can override that).  If it doesn't know, then future attempts at a simple `merge` will make git cross, and you have to keep track of the "real" upstream (content-wise) on your own, such as with the `rebaseUpstream` tag in my example below.

---

Well, your text and your picture don't say exactly the same thing.

The picture is what you get simply by merging with the `--no-ff` option.  So when `dev` is at `A` and `wip` is at `d`, you merge into `dev` creating `D` - a single commit which, to `dev`, represents everything you did from `b`, `c`, and `d` on `wip`.

Now you might think I'm mistaken because if you do a `git log` from `dev` you can still see `b`, `c`, and `d` as separate commits.  That's because git is trying to help you fully understand the history of `D`, and to prevent it you would give `git log` the `--first-parent` option (so that it only looks "up" the `dev` branch).  In that case you'd need to make sure your merge commits have good commit messages.

But what you wrote that you want is something different - also doable but a little hairier.  If you did a squash-and-rebase, `D` would not be a child of `d` - that's why I say your picture shows a merge.

The trick to making it work with `rebase` is to understand that `rebase` *does not* destroy commits, even though in normal usage it looks as though it did.  You can see that it doesn't by getting two branches pointed at the same commit, and rebase one of them.  And in fact that's how you can do what you're asking.

But be warned: madness this way lies.

So let's go back to your diagram.  At the beginning, you have `dev` and `wip` both at A.  Put a tag here, because we'll always want to know how much of `wip` is already on `dev`.

```
git tag rebaseUpstream
```

Now do some work per your desired workflow, until you have `wip` at `d`.  Then

```
git checkout -b rebaseTip
git rebase --interactive --onto master rebaseUpstream
```

Now you're in a todo list editor, so change the instructions for `c` and `d` from `pick` to `squash`, then let 'er rip.  Then of course you'll get to edit the squashed commit message.

Now you have two lines of development pointing up to `dev` - one with just `D` and one with `b`, `c`, and `d`.  Next we need to update `dev`.

```
git checkout dev
git merge rebaseTip
git branch --delete rebaseTip
```

Now the trouble with this is that git doesn't know that `D` and `d` have any relationship.  On the plus side that means `git log` or similar, when done on `dev`, will show what you hoped for - without need of extra options.  But the bad news is, if you're not careful you'll lose track of how much of `wip` is on `dev`.  To mitigate this risk

```
git checkout wip
git tag -f rebaseUpstream
```

And now you can resume your workflow on the `wip` branch, and repeat the whole thing as often as you like.

Comment: This is right: given the (somewhat conflicting) desires, using a regular `--no-ff` merge seems like the best process. Note that for viewing purposes on `master` you can use `git log --first-parent` to ignore all the incoming merges.

Comment: Thanks! This is overall helpful, but more convoluted than I would like. I think I will do as @pathfinderelite suggested and just squash in the **wip** branch and do a merge into **dev**.The **wip** branch supposed to be exclusive to me, is temporary, and will be deleted. Also, some of the commits on it will not build or just be incomplete work. I don't actually want a history of those commits. I just want the 1 squashed commit that actually represents a real piece of work to be merged into **dev**.

Answer (score 0):

One possible aproach to tackle this problem is to make diff patch between d and h commits, apply it to local master branch, commit it as H and push H to master.

```
git diff d-hash..h-hash > newcommit.patch

git checkout master

git am -p < newcommit.patch

git commit -a -m "Implement H"

git push
```

- you can write this as shell/ruby/ phyton script and save it as git-commname (in user/bin) that accepts two params (eg. d-hash, h-hash) and call it as

  > git commname d-hash h-hash